# Intersection types assignable definition

Tags: typescript

We see definition for intersection of types in

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622

**A & B is assignable to X if A is assignable to X or B is assignable to X.**

```
type A = {x:1}
type B = {y:1}

type I = A & B 

declare function f(t:{x:1;y:1}):void

let i:I = {} as I
let a:A = {} as A
let b:B = {} as B

f(a) // error
f(b) // error
f(i) // ok
```

As we can see **A** *{x:1}* and **B** *{y:1}* not assignable to **X** *{x:1;y:1}* but **I** assignable to **X**.

Is it definition wrong? Or I miss something?

Comment: This is correct because an intersection "merges" the two types together.

Comment: @catgirlkelly yes, but definition says other things, definition doesn't say about any "merges"

Comment: @Oleg the definition is confusing isn't it? A is NOT assignable to (A & B) and neither is B..? Only (A merged with B) is assignable to (A & B).

Comment: @BenClayton yes, it is, my question about that confusing

Answer (score 0):

The definition is alright.

---

"`X` is assignable to `Y`" is another way to say "`X` is a subtype of `Y`". So you can rephrase the definition like this:

> A & B is a subtype of X if A is a subtype of X or B is a subtype of X

For example, if you have a value of type `Cat & Warm`, you can put it into a variable of type `Cat`, a variable of type `Warm` and a variable of type `Animal` (because `Cat` is a subtype of `Animal`). In other words, `Cat & Warm` is a subtype of `Cat`, a subtype of `Warm`, and a subtype of `Animal`.

---

> As we can see A {x:1} and B {y:1} not assignable to X {x:1;y:1} but I assignable to X.

Correct, `A` is not assignable to `A & B`, and `B` is not assignable to `A & B`. The definition is claiming that `A & B` is assignable to `A` and `A & B` is assignable to `B`.

"`X` is assignable to `Y`" means that if you have a variable `x` of type `X`, this is legal:

```
const y: Y = x
```

So this is legal:

```
const a: A = a_and_b
const b: B = a_and_b
```

but this is not:

```
const ab: A & B = a
const ab: A & B = b
```

---

Example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAPAXFAjAXygH2QC8MAWAJmwChRIoAhBZdLKm6AYUaRAwssoBmAVwB2AY2ABLAPYioAgBQAjMRgYAyKOwCUySlANQxsgM7AoStYxUGA9LagB5ANIAaCxDEBDISegatKEkTKC8TE0kAcxEvJQAbaGBpen1DYxEzIwxORBsoeyc3D29ffyhNTmDQ8KiY+MTk9lSDdMyvDDhcsTsHFysqrygTISU2KGkBWHcTZIDKkLCI6NiEqCTYSmwgA)):

```
type A = {x: 1} | {z: 42}
type B = {x: 1}
type C = {y: 2}

function f(bc: B & C) {
    const b: B = bc  // OK, because B & C is assignable to B
    const c: C = bc  // OK, because B & C is assignable to C
    const a: A = bc  // OK: B is assignable to A, so B & C is assignable to A
}

function g(b: B) {
    const bc: B & C = b  // not OK: doesn't work the other way around
}
```

In your example, you're doing the thing from `function g` when calling the `f` functions with `a` and `b` as arguments. This will cause an error because `A` is not assignable to `A & B` and `B` is not assignable to `A & B`.

Comment: `"X is assignable to Y" is another way to say "X is a subtype of Y"` is a good summary. It's worth mentioning that the reason TypeScript uses the word "assignable" and not "subtype" is that "subtype" is generally regarded as a transitive relation, where "assignable" in TypeScript is very much not transitive (`number` is assignable to `any` and `any` to `string`, but `number` is not assignable to `string`).

Comment: you say "that A & B is a subtype of X if A is a subtype of X or B is a subtype of X", but in my case A isn't subtype of X and B isn't subtype of X

Comment: @Oleg I think that's not the definition of assignability of an intersection type. Meaning, the **if** in the phrase is not **if and only if**. In particular, as you said, `A & B` is assignable to `A & B`, even though `A` is not a subtype of `A & B`, and neither is `B`. This is covered by the second bullet point from Anders Hejlsberg's post: "`X` is assignable to `A & B` if `X` is assignable to `A` and `X` is assignable to `B`"

Comment: You want to say me that we have to consider that definition in conjunction with two bullet point?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding you: >{you say "that A & B is a subtype of X if A is a subtype of X or B is a subtype of X", but in my case A isn't subtype of X and B isn't subtype of X}. What is `X` in your case?

Comment: X is {x:1, y:1}

Comment: If you scroll down the GitHub issue a bit, you see that [originally](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3622#issuecomment-116861578) the sentence was "A & B is assignable to A and assignable to B", so I interpret the sentence as just a more accurate version of that, not a complete definition. I don't think there's a complete mathematical definition of TypeScript's rules if that's what you're looking for. (except the implementation, perhaps) (P.S. maybe we should move this to chat?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245045/discussion-between-oleg-and-decorator-factory).